# Remove text specifying mode "INSERT" in bottom vim line

Tags: vimscript, neovim

[image]

In the bottom two lines, you'll see the statusline saying "INSERT", and the line where you enter commands showing `-- INSERT --`

This is quite redundant, and I would like any recommendations on how to remove the text that comes by default in vim saying what mode it is, with hyphens on either side.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You might want to see [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604). Please [edit] and trim down the vimrc; a smaller example is better.

Comment: Looking at my vimrc and the answer, there doesn't seem to be any useful information in the vimrc that would help elucidate the question, so I'm just going to remove the vimrc and hope that doing so doesn't make anything fuzzier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on the FAQ for vim-airline (which is the Vim plug-in adding the mode to your status bar), in [this question](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-default-mode-indicator):

> How do I get rid of the default mode indicator?
>
> Add `set noshowmode` to your vimrc.